# Why was my post put on hold?

Tags: support, specific-question, close-reasons

Why was the [shortest λ sort post](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/55231/sort-a-list-of-numbers-on-the-%CE%BB-calculus/55233#55233) put on hold? What is "unclear" about it? The only question raised (about church encodings) was promptly clarified in the post as soon as it was pointed.

Comment: I'd be more interested to know why it hasn't been reopened. Hopefully one of the three people who voted "Leave closed" in the reopen review queue will answer.

Comment: Note for curious parties: The post has since been reopened.